# overlapping controls, windows store apps c#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have 2 rectangles and they are overlapping each other. Is it possible to choose which one is show on front?

Now i use opacity to test everything. Is there a BringToFront function or can i change the z-index?

Comment: If you can use a Canvas there is an Attached [zorder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.zindex.aspx) Property.  Also see this [MSDN Forum Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/88eb7e36-5a2a-4317-afff-fb936430f964)

Comment: See the second link that I added, the accepted answer has to do with removing, then adding the control back to the control collection since z-order is dependent on the order the control was added to the Xaml